# sed remove ze if ze is alone on the line

Tags: sed

Ubuntu, `sed` remove `ze` if `ze` is alone on the line

The closest I got is `sed "s/\bze\b//g"` and `sed "s/^\bze\b//g"` which does not produce the desired result.

Before sed:

```
ze.com
example.ze
zero.com
ze
```

After sed:

```
ze.com
example.ze
zero.com
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [line anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) rather than word boundaries

```
$ sed '/^ze$/d' file
ze.com
example.ze
zero.com
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `grep`:

```
$ grep -vxF ze file
ze.com
example.ze
zero.com
```

The used options:

- `-v` negates the sense of the match so that only lines *not* matching the pattern are returned.
- `-x` requires that the pattern matches a complete line from start to finish.
- `-F` tells `grep` that the pattern is a fixed string and not a regular expression.

---

The issue with your `sed` expressions is that a substitution *modifies* a line in the input, but it will never *delete* a line.  The pattern `\bze\b` will correctly match the complete word `ze`, but that word exists on other lines too, not only on the last line.

To delete a line with `sed`, use its `d` command together with a regular expression that matches the line that you'd like to remove, such as `^ze$`, as [steeldriver shows in his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/460442/116858).

For the *specific example* (removing the last line),

```
sed '$d' file
```

would also be an option.  Here, `$` is not a regular expression (since it's not within `/.../`) but the special *address* of the last line in the file.